# Windows update to notify?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I have changed the windows update option to notify on my win2003 datacenter edition as I don't want it downloading anything while the server is running but to notify me so I can schedule the best time for it to be downloaded and installed.

The problem now is that it won't show up or download anything.

- Is there a way to summon the update to make sure everything is up to
  date ?
- What should I verify in order to make sure it is working as I
  configured ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you can do / check:

1. The System Event log should contain entries from source `NtServicePack` whenever the update service detects available updates, downloads, or installs them.
2. You can manually fire a check with the command: wuauclt /detectnow
3. Open IE (if you can) and go out the MS update website and ensure you have the most current version of the Update client installed.

BTW doesn't sound like a WSUS is being used. If so, maybe the updates have not be released to this system or the system is in a client target group the updates aren't approved for yet.

All else fails, you can stop the Automatic Updates service, delete the C:\Windows\Software Distribution folder, restart the service and force the manual check.  Perhaps there is something corrupt in the Software Distribution folder mucking things up.

Comment: `wuauclt /detectnow` doesnt seem to trigger I had the taskmgr open at the time and didnt see it up at all so I went to the website and got the updates from there, is it ok to get it from there or not the same thing ?

Comment: The update service gets its data from the Windows Update website - so same thing, just different way to accomplish it.

Comment: thanks it seems that after i used the website update once the win2003 update started working again.